# What is meant by "genes involved in the stress response"?

Tags: genetics, homework

I would like to know about the term stress response. For example "some genes of a species under study is involved in stress response". What does that mean? I got this as a part of my assignment question.
[image]

Comment: In which context did you find this phrase?

Comment: Sounds like genes that are activated during stress, e.g. during the [pathway of cortisol synthesis](http://rgd.mcw.edu/rgdweb/pathway/pathwayRecord.html?acc_id=PW:0000569).

Comment: heat shock proteins are the first thing that came to my mind! could you elaborate on the type or the context of stress?

Comment: @Chris : Please see the edit.

Answer (score 2):

The comment by @fileunderwater is apt: stress-response-related genes are genes that are activated during stress, such as exposure to heat. In bacteria, for example, there are heat-shock proteins that are involved in keeping the tertiary structure of proteins (folding/3D shape) intact during periods of heat exposure. Genes encoding these heat shock proteins are then called to be upregulated, and you would find them back in a typical micro array experiment. Hope this helps.